# Django image upload to Amazon S3 fails with boto

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, boto

I have been struggling for a while trying to make media file uploads to Amazon S3 from Django work, and would be very thankful if anyone could help.

My app uploads image files without issues locally with a Sqlite3 database as well as Postgres, but when I try to upload my media files to S3, I get the following 500 error:

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

**Update November 29th**

It seems boto cannot find my bucket name, even if it is set in my settings. The '`NoneType'` above comes from the following, which is from `connection.py` and `bucket.py`:

```
bucket: None
```

I have installed django-storages and boto, like described in the following articles:

- [Using Amazon S3 to Store your Django Site's Static and Media Files](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/)
- [Django-Storages and Amazon S3](http://martinbrochhaus.com/s3.html)
- [Using AWS S3 to Store Static Assets and File Uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)

I tested uploading my media files to my bucket on S3 manually, and the database instances that I created locally links to correct media files from my bucket. From my point of view, the issue occurs when my django view tries to upload the image to S3 via boto (`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in my `local_settings.py`).

The following is in my `local_settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'storages',
)

# Local postgres database
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "name",
        "USER": "username",
        "PASSWORD": "pw",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'my-key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'my-key2'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket-name'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
```

In my upload form in `views.py` I use something like:

```
photo = form.cleaned_data['photo']
...
recipe = Recipe(title=title, ..., photo=photo)
recipe.save()
```

I also tried adding a s3utils.py file like described in [2](http://martinbrochhaus.com/s3.html). Bucket policy and CORS is added like described in above articles. I granted "Everyone" access to upload/delete.

My `requirements.txt` contains:

```
Django==1.7.8
Pillow==2.6.1
awscli==1.7.36
boto==2.38.0
botocore==1.0.1
django-storages==1.1.8
whitenoise==1.0.6
...
```

I use Heroku for my app, and will need to store and host media files from S3.

Does anyone see what I am missing? Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Traceback**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/add/

Django Version: 1.7.8
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'matboken_app',
 'crispy_forms',
 'PIL',
 'django_summernote',
 'djangoratings',
 'imagekit',
 'storages',
 's3direct')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/matboken_app/views.py" in addRecipe
  678.             recipe.save()
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  589.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  617.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  698.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  731.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  878.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  301.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  89.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  51.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py" in _save
  385.         key = self.bucket.get_key(encoded_name)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py" in get_key
  192.         key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py" in _get_key_internal
  199.                                                 query_args=query_args)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py" in make_request
  652.         auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
File "/Users/Kenneth/Dropbox/matboken/env_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py" in build_auth_path
  94.             path = '/' + bucket

Exception Type: TypeError at /add/
Exception Value: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: I set up my project to upload files to s3 via the admin. It was fairly straightforward using django-s3direct. I have the project up on github at https://github.com/zsoobhan/prometheus. From your error it seems that some code in your view is trying to add a `string` to a `Nonetype` i.e. `'foo' + None` will throw that same error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ziyad. Django-s3direct looks interesting, and I will give it a try. It will not solve the issue with boto, but if it makes my uploads work, I will be happy!

Comment: https://github.com/zsoobhan/prometheus/blob/master/www/content/models.py#L27-L36 and https://github.com/zsoobhan/prometheus/blob/master/www/content/admin.py#L15:L18 would be pretty much all you would need to upload content to your bucket. Good luck.

Comment: I still struggle to make this work. Please see my update above. My bucket region is Frankfurt if that matters.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. Put the full stack trace up. Maybe there is something that you missed.

Comment: Please see my update above. Thanks!

Comment: hmm here's  a stab in the dark `AWS_BUCKET_NAME = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket-name'`. I would put a pdb.set_trace and work my way up the stack to find what's calling the function with `None` instead of `my-bucket-name`